# Magento 2 Configerable and Bundle Image Swap / swatch

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product, product-images, bundled-product

I believe this function is built into Magento now, but I cant get it to work or find any further instruction on settings,

If I have a bundle product for bulb types (A),  which has a selection of different bulbs available, all with there own image (1,2,3) I would like the images to appear in the basket and if possible on the main screen.

Desired function 
When user goes in it displays the main image for the bundle,  when the user selects option 1 I would like it to swap the image for product 1(ideally from it simple child product or an uploaded image in the bundle product)  in the main screen or atleast in the basket.

I know this can be done for colours from a pre-set swatch file , but i cant see a way of doing it for other attributes from its own images.

I would also like to do the same with configurable products, based on the products selected.

actual function 
no images change and no matter what is select in the basket it just shows the main bundle image thumbnail

I have checked configuration -> sales > shopping cart- and set grouped product and configurable image to "product thumbnail itself" but I don't know if I'm missing a setting in the image box, is there a label I should add to the image

I am using Magento 2.2 on a custom theme (unero)

Thanks

David

Comment: check if you have same setting for the store view as well, or check by reindexing once

Comment: Thanks I have checked they are all set the same, and I have re-indexed again to check, is there certain settings needing to be set?

Comment: No I believe, if you have set any custom theme, try once to check these settings with luma theme